# How to resolve asynchronous process before moving onto another process?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, callback

I have the following method in which I read from a csv and collect the data in an array of strings. After I do that I want to use that array. I'm new to handling asynchronous calls and I think what's happening in the code below is that reading from the .csv file is asynchronous so the array is empty once I start looping through it. How do I complete the .csv reading so that all the array is filled completely and only until it is, move on to the next task of looping through the array?

```
    static async readAndPopulateGMDevicesToMigrate() {
            const bookTitles = [];
            await fs.createReadStream('./BookTitles.csv')
                .pipe(csv())
                .on('data', (data) => bookTitles.push(data.Titles))
                .on('error', (error) => loggingService.getDefaultLogger().error(error))
                .on('end', () => loggingService.getDefaultLogger().info("Book Titles:" + booksTitles));
            
            console.log(bookTitles);
            const booksToAdd = [];
    
            bookTitles.forEach(bookTitle => booksToAdd.push(new Object({
                Title: bookTitle}))),
            })))
    
            console.log(readDevices);
}
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: `await` waits for `Promise`s to resolve ... `fs.createReadStream` does NOT return a Promise

Comment: try changing your code to https://pastebin.com/vaUdSSzH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of pointers, hoping this can help with getting the approach clear.

1. `createReadStream` returns a `ReadableStream`, not an async/promise to await on.
2. The returned `ReadableStream` provides means to react to events, as shown when pipelining the handlers by using `on`.

Now, if you wrap your code in a `Promise` where either `resolve` or `reject` base on the `end` or `error` event respectively.

```
static async readAndPopulateGMDevicesToMigrate() {
        const bookTitles = [];
        const logger = loggingService.getDefaultLogger();
        /* WRAP in promise to wait */
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fs.createReadStream('./BookTitles.csv')
                .pipe(csv())
                .on('data', ({ Titles }) => {
                    logger.info(`Adding ${Titles} Titles`);
                    bookTitles.push(Titles);
                })
                .on('error', (error) => {
                    logger.error(error);
                    /* REJECT on error, maybe reject with the partial result ? */
                    reject(error);
                })
                .on('end', () => {
                    logger.info("Book Titles:" + booksTitles);
                    const booksToAdd = bookTitles.map(bookTitle => ({Title: bookTitle}));
                    /* RESOLVE when the stream was read to the end */
                    resolve(booksToAdd);
                });
        
        })

        console.log(bookTitles);    
        console.log(readDevices);
}
```